# softassert not being called.. Only getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

In one my testcase I am trying to find whether an element is displayed after login.

```
softAssert.assertTrue(landing1PageFuncs.getSetupBtn().isDisplayed(), "Login Failed");
softAssert.assertAll();
```

> getSetupBtn getter method is as below

```
public WebElement getSetupBtn() {
    return AppWait.waitForElement(driver, setupBtn , Constants.WAITTIME);
}
```

> waitForElement function is as below

```
public static WebElement waitForElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int timeOutInSeconds) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_WAIT_4_ELEMENT, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //reset implicitlyWait
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn(element + " not found even after waiting for: " + timeOutInSeconds + " seconds");
        logger.warn(e, new RuntimeException());
    }
    return element;
}
```

But what I am observing is that isDisplayed method is never invoked. Hence the soft assertion is not being fired.

All I get is the exception as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='page_content_inner']/div/a[1]/div"}
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'justdial', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-86-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 6b9e0607-ee41-42b8-bb58-0f7d6cc32481
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='page_content_inner']/div/a[1]/div}

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
    at org.justdial.jdomni.functionaltests.LoginPageTests.chkLoginWithValidCred(LoginPageTests.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
```

What I am doing wrong? I am looking for a solution which goes till the Assertion and says "Login Failed"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your element cannot be found, so `isDisplayed()` cannot be determined. `isDisplayed()` can only be called on an element that exists and has already been found, that is why your assertion is never called.

`landing1PageFuncs.getSetupBtn()` throws an exception before `isDisplayed()` is being called.

If you want to find out if an element exists on the page, you should use `driver.findElements(By.xpath('locator')).size > 0` instead of `driver.findElement(By.xpath('locator').isDisplayed()`

Comment: But then when is that method isDisplayed() even present?

Comment: You can use isDisplayed() to find if an element that exists (in the DOM) is visible or not. For example when you set a certain field value, you want another field to become invisible so it is no longer user editable. You can check for this with isDisplayed().

Answer (score 0):

```
Since the element is not available in DOM, u cannot apply a soft assertion and obviously u'll get NoSuchElementException. 

you can write a utility method like below to verify the whether the locator exists or not in the DOM.

public class verifyloc {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        String loc = "//input[@id='lst-ib']";
        By locator = verifyElementPresent(driver, loc);

        System.out.println("Locator is : " + locator);
    }

    public static By verifyElementPresent(WebDriver driver, String locator) {

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
            return By.xpath(locator);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return null;
        }
        
    }
}
```